# Firebase deploy command is deploying a very old commit

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I use

```
firebase deploy
```

on my react app it deploys files way back in history. How do I get it to deploy my most recent committed changes

Comment: did you build before running firebase deploy?

Comment:  I totally forgot

Comment: No worries, it happens :)

Answer (score 1):

You should build your project before running `firebase deploy` (make sure you did that).